# How to get the process Id of not responding foreground app?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, pinvoke

I have a process which monitors the window which the user is currently working([GetForegroundWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx)). To get process ID by HWND I use [GetWindowThreadProcessId](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522(v=vs.85).aspx). But, if foreground app is hung, I will get the process Id of [Desktop Window Manager - dwm.exe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_Window_Manager). I can determine is app hung by [IsHungAppWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633526%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). **But how to get real process Id of foreground hung app?**

Comment: Is using the `System.Diagnostics.Process` Class an option for you ?

Comment: @user3185569, what is the benefit of System.Diagnostics.Process in my situation?

Comment: You tried to filter out the dwm.exe?

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan You can use it to query the processes that are not responding and get their Process ID.

Comment: @user3185569, it's not clear. Could you give some examples?

Comment: @Essigwurst, what will it give to me?

Comment: Sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/205381). What are you ultimately trying to achieve?

Comment: @IInspectable, as it's written in the header: How to get the process Id of not responding foreground app?

Comment: Me: *"Why are you crossing the road? What's your ultimate goal?"* - You: *"I need to get to the other side of the road."*

Comment: @IInspectable, let's imagine that it's utility that logs hangs(currently active ) apps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use undocumented methods from user32.dll HungWindowFromGhostWindow to get the real window handle from ghost handle (If windows is hung, dwm create its ghost copy).
[image: Undocumented functions: HungWindowFromGhostWindow and GhostWindowFromHungWindow]

```
namespace HungProcessName
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System;

    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GhostWindowFromHungWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr HungWindowFromGhostWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool IsHungAppWindow(IntPtr hwnd);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, out uint procId);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                var hwnd = GetForegroundWindow();
                Console.WriteLine("Foreground window: {0}", hwnd);
                if (IsHungAppWindow(hwnd))
                {
                    var hwndReal = HungWindowFromGhostWindow(hwnd);
                    uint procId = 0;
                    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwndReal, out procId);
                    if (procId > 0)
                    {
                        Process proc = null;
                        try { proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)procId); }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Could not get proces with Id '{0}': {1}", procId, ex);
                        }
                        if (proc != null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Ghost hwnd: {0}, Real hwnd: {1}. ProcessId: {2}, Proccess name: {3}",
                                hwnd, hwndReal, procId, proc.ProcessName);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would we want to use this undocumented api? You appreciate the risks surely? You realise that you aren't supposed to do this? And who says that a hung window has a ghost window. Often times they don't. Process can disable ghosting. Also window can hang and not be ghosted because nobody has yet tried to interact with it.

Comment: @David Heffernan, at least TaskManager[taskmgr.exe] [uses this technique](http://i67.tinypic.com/34dkl6f.png). I gave test code. Before checking one can send [SendMessageTimeout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/windows/desktop/ms644952(v=vs.85).aspx) with WM_NULL. Of course, if someone called [DisableProcessWindowsGhosting](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648415(v=vs.85).aspx) it will not work. Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Well task manager is part of the is shell. Of course it can use private api calls. You cannot though. The problem with the question is that we don't know why you are asking. Perhaps your real problem has a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

Well using C#, `System.Diagnostics` and `System.Linq` you can do this:

```
List<IntPtr> handles = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
                                                 .Where(x => !x.Responding)
                                                 .Select(x => x.MainWindowHandle).ToList();
```

Which returns the handles of the processes that are not responding.

Comment: It will give process Ids of not responding apps. But how to map it with foreground window?

Comment: Should I use Process.MainWindowHandle?

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan the process must have an interface for `MainWindowHandle` to work.

Comment: at first I accepted your answer because it really gets the hung apps. But if the foreground app is hung, GetForegroundWindow will return ghost window HWND (which is created by DWM), not real window HWND. Do you know any other ideas how to convert ghost HWND to real HWND without using undocumented functions such in my example?